# How do I create a proper Memory Poolfor a Multithreaded vector (LFSV)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, memory-management, memory-pool

Below is an old exercise for a class that is no longer being taught at my university (Parallel Processing).  The goal is to create and use a Memory Bank to speed up the Lock-Free Sorted Vector implementation.  I implemented the Memory Bank myself and the goal is to set aside enough memory to use so I do not have to use new or delete in the LFSV.  I believe I need a Get() function that returns the address of the memory (not sure how keep track of the unused memory) and Store should free the memory (somehow mark it as unused).

Inside LFSV (which worked perfectly fine before my intervention), the exercise explains that I should replace the new and delete with new replacement and Store(memory we want freed). How do I go about creating the Get(if this is incorrect) or the Store function to perform like a proper memory bank?  I will also take any reference or memory bank examples online that you may know of because I am having trouble finding good resources related to memory banks and multithreading.

There are no errors in this program, but it returns as a "FAIL" since I did not properly manage the memory bank.

```
#include <algorithm>//copy, random_shuffle
#include <ctime>    //std::time (NULL) to seed srand
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <atomic>         // std::atomic
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <vector>         // std::vector
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex
#include <deque>          // std::deque

class MemoryBank 
{
    std::deque< std::vector<int>* > slots;
public:
    MemoryBank() : slots(10000) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<10000; ++i) 
        {
            slots[i] = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(new char[sizeof(std::vector<int>)]);
        }
    }
    ~MemoryBank()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < slots.size(); ++i)
        {
            delete slots[i];
        }
        slots.clear();
    }
    void * Get() 
    { 
        return &slots; 
    }
    void Store(std::vector<int *> freeMemory)
    {
        return;
    }
};

class LFSV {
    std::atomic< std::vector<int>* > pdata;
    std::mutex wr_mutex;
    MemoryBank mb;

    public:

    LFSV() : mb(), pdata( new (mb.Get()) std::vector<int> ) {}   

    ~LFSV() 
    { 
        mb.~MemoryBank();
    }

    void Insert( int const & v ) {
        std::vector<int> *pdata_new = nullptr, *pdata_old;
        int attempt = 0;
        do {
            ++attempt;
            delete pdata_new;
            pdata_old = pdata;
            pdata_new = new (mb.Get())std::vector<int>( *pdata_old );

            std::vector<int>::iterator b = pdata_new->begin();
            std::vector<int>::iterator e = pdata_new->end();
            if ( b==e || v>=pdata_new->back() ) { pdata_new->push_back( v ); } //first in empty or last element
            else {
                for ( ; b!=e; ++b ) {
                    if ( *b >= v ) {
                        pdata_new->insert( b, v );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
//            std::lock_guard< std::mutex > write_lock( wr_mutex );
//            std::cout << "insert " << v << "(attempt " << attempt << ")" << std::endl;
        } while ( !(this->pdata).compare_exchange_weak( pdata_old, pdata_new  ));
        // LEAKing pdata_old since "delete pdata_old;" will cause errors


//        std::lock_guard< std::mutex > write_lock( wr_mutex );
//        std::vector<int> * pdata_current = pdata;
//        std::vector<int>::iterator b = pdata_current->begin();
//        std::vector<int>::iterator e = pdata_current->end();
//        for ( ; b!=e; ++b ) {
//            std::cout << *b << ' ';
//        }
//        std::cout << "Size " << pdata_current->size() << " after inserting " << v << std::endl;
    }

    int const& operator[] ( int pos ) const {
        return (*pdata)[ pos ];
    }
};

LFSV lfsv;

void insert_range( int b, int e ) {
    int * range = new int [e-b];
    for ( int i=b; i<e; ++i ) {
        range[i-b] = i;
    }
    std::srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time (NULL)) );
    std::random_shuffle( range, range+e-b );
    for ( int i=0; i<e-b; ++i ) {
        lfsv.Insert( range[i] );
    }
    delete [] range;
}

int reader( int pos, int how_many_times ) {
    int j = 0;
    for ( int i=1; i<how_many_times; ++i ) {
        j = lfsv[pos];
    }
    return j;
}

std::atomic<bool> doread( true );

void read_position_0() {
    int c = 0;
    while ( doread.load() ) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 10 ) );
        if ( lfsv[0] != -1 ) {
            std::cout << "not -1 on iteration " << c << "\n"; // see main - all element are non-negative, so index 0 should always be -1
        }
        ++c;
    }
}

void test( int num_threads, int num_per_thread )
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    lfsv.Insert( -1 );
    std::thread reader = std::thread( read_position_0 );

    for (int i=0; i<num_threads; ++i) {
        threads.push_back( std::thread( insert_range, i*num_per_thread, (i+1)*num_per_thread ) );
    }
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    doread.store( false );
    reader.join();

    for (int i=0; i<num_threads*num_per_thread; ++i) { 
        //        std::cout << lfsv[i] << ' '; 
        if ( lfsv[i] != i-1 ) {
            std::cout << "Error\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "All good\n";
}

void test0() { test( 1, 100 ); }
void test1() { test( 2, 100 ); }
void test2() { test( 8, 100 ); }
void test3() { test( 100, 100 ); }

void (*pTests[])() = { 
    test0,test1,test2,test3//,test4,test5,test6,test7
}; 


#include <cstdio>    /* sscanf */
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    if (argc==2) { //use test[ argv[1] ]
        int test = 0;
        std::sscanf(argv[1],"%i",&test);
        try {
            pTests[test]();
        } catch( const char* msg) {
            std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: These are more commonly called memory pools.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` is really a "I know what I'm doing, trust me" cast. The compiler will - if possible - believe you.

However, in this case it's entirely wrong. `new char[]` does *not* return a `vector<int>*`.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for the "reinterpret_cast?"

Comment: @AmrotheStudent: The _syntax_ used is correct according to the grammar. However, the logic behind this is just flawed. I can't see an easy fix. What are these slots supposed to contain? I see 4 methods, and 4 different types (`new char[], vector<int>, vector<int*>, void*`).

Comment: I believe the Get() function is used to give the new placement in LFSV class a location to use the memory.  And I believe new placement requires a void *.  The LFSV is a vector<int*> which is managed by the Memory Bank.

The line:
    slots[i] = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(new char[sizeof(std::vector<int>)]);

was in the Memory Bank skeleton that the exercise had for getting started, so I am not sure if that is right or wrong since I am not familiar with reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @AmrotheStudent: I wouldn't trust that exercise, and in fact it's so bad that I would distrust its author as well.

Comment: I am trying to practice multithreading techniques for beginners but it is tough to find exercises simple enough to understand.  Do you have any good references I can use to better learn multithreading?

Comment: @AmrotheStudent: No, but the code above suggests that you're still struggling with single-threaded C++. And lock-free multithreading isn't the best place to start learning multi-threading either. Ordinary `std::thread` and `std::mutex` might be better.

Comment: I've done many other multithreaded exercises that involved multiple threads sorting a range or evaluating and updating a map of values, but I am not familiar with new placement or managing a memory pool.  The information for this exercise was sparse, and it's not easy to find similar exercises online.